# counting number of lines of a text file in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I need to open and count the number of lines in a text file using a stored procedure. The stored procedure should return a value whenever executed. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you need to use a stored procedure for this? Seems ill-purposed.

Comment: It may be a good idea to give us some hint which Sybase DB and which version you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

In Sybase it is simple.

> > `EXEC @LineCount = xp_cmdshell(unix_command)`
> >
> > (Your DBA might have to fiddle around a tiny bit if they have not set the XP server up, but it comes on the CD, is fully documented, very easy (for a DBA), etc.)

The Unix command is of course word count, with the -line operator (indicating you want a count of lines):

> > `santosh$ wc -l file_name`

MS is identical, at least the last time I used it.  But the issue there is, getting the line count on the MS-DOS side.  If you have Cygwin or similar then use the Unix command.